# ARAnimation rendering stop working without any code change

Tags: sony-smarteyeglass

Could there be any reason why `sendARAnimationObject` should stop working without any change in the code? Does rendering of bitmaps in a timer depend on any external state like battery level or sensor state etc?

Another issue is that if I use `sendARAnimationObjectWithCallback` the callback method in the listener `onResultSendAnimationObject` is never called as stated in the documentation. Could there be any other dependency causing this callback method not called at all?

Comment: I am overriding even `onAREnableAnimationResponse` and `onARDisableAnimationResponse`. Even though I am not calling `disableARAnimationRequest` the callback method is called with result 0 and the callback method `onAREnableAnimationResponse` is called some number of times (about 50) with result 3 which means no success I guess but no idea what 3 means.

Answer (score 1):

It works much better with the official SDK v1.0

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I hope SDK v1.0, resolved the problem completely.

Comment: It feels like it is coming and going. Even though I have new SDK it happens sometimes that the problem described above reappears.

Comment: I don't know why but uninstalling/installing Smarteyeglass app from Sony solved the problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

Now I belive I found the main reason behind. I was not calling `disableARAnimationRequest` anywhere in my app. Now I am calling it in onPause and it works much better next time I start the app and call `enableARAnimationRequest`. But I would need someone at sony to confirm this kind of behaviour. Maybe the disable method should be called in some SDK method without putting that burden on the developer. Or some kind of cleanup in SDK when you start your app and enable animation request.